# Apply filter on asp.net mvc model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I've a model which contains 100 records. My requirement is to bind only 10 records to my grid. Is there any chance to do like this?

I'm working with asp.net mvc

Comment: Why don't you filter using LINQ? And pass that along to the grid?

Comment: Yes we can apply in LINQ. But once result come back from LINQ query and store it in my model, is there any way to get it done or not... Just I want to do like this. i.e filter at client side not at server side